# Angularjs response status doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to catch response status of GET call but it's doesn't work

```
$http({
            url: conf.url + 'page/' + $rootScope.name,
            method: "GET"
        })
            .then(function(response) { //200-299 status works correctly
             $rootScope.passwrd = response.data.password;                
             location.href = '#/page';
            },
            function(response) { //500 status: response = SyntaxError: Unexpected token F at Object.parse (native) at fromJson
                if (response.status == 500) {  //response.status = underfined
                    alert('Server error')
                } else {
                    alert('Other error');
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you post the json you return from the server? The problem is there

Comment: json contain only text: "Failed to generate phrase"
Error in console: GET http://blalbalba/page/name 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your server is sending invalid JSON as said in your comment which is making angularjs parsing crash when he tries to read the result from the server and parse it from json to javascript object.

```
// response = SyntaxError: Unexpected token F at Object.parse (native) at fromJson
```

Check the JSON send by your server (copy/paste it on jsonlint.com to validate it).

If it's not JSON, then check that the Content-type of your response is not json.

Answer (score 1):

you have to return a valid json object
meaning:

```
{ "message" : "Failed to generate phrase" }
```

instead of just the string `"Failed to generate phrase"`

Comment: I'm already trying debug it, but value of response.message is "Unexpected token F"

Comment: what lang/framework  you use server side? Can you post the relevant code from the server where you return the error?

Comment: a json cannot contain just a string like that's why you have a parse error. Meaning the problem lies **server** side

Comment: Yes, json was invalid. Thank you so much!